# After Dax's rite of closure does she now have some of the past memories of the temporary hosts?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

DS9 "Facets":

> DAX: The zhian'tara is a ritual where joined Trills get a chance to
>   actually meet their previous hosts.
>
> KIRA: Meet them? How?
>
> DAX: That's where you come in. If you don't mind, **I'd like to borrow**
>   **your bodies for a few hours**.
>
> O'BRIEN: What do you mean borrow our bodies?
>
> DAX: If you agree to participate, the memories of one of my previous
>   hosts will be temporarily removed from the symbiont and imprinted onto
>   you. **You essentially become one of my hosts for the duration of the**
>   **ritual.**
>
> BASHIR: And how is this accomplished?

Does Dax now have some of the memories of the temporary hosts, Bashir, Quark, O'Brien, etc.? (I'm **not** asking about the memories during short time they are bonded, I'm asking about the **previous memories** of the temporary hosts.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no mention in any canonical story that Dax retains any memories at all from the zhian'tara, other than Jadzia's own memories of having talked to the various past hosts through her friends. In fact, the events of "Facets" are never really mentioned again.

Comment: However, the sentences in bold would support that it's indeed the case. BTW - thinking on it, it's incorrect to speak of those personalities as "previous hosts". After joining becomes permanent, there is basically one person with memories of multiple lives.
And back to issue - the previous personalities have access to host's memories, are aware of their state and are transferred from Dax to that host, IIRC "deleting" them from Dax's memory... And at the end recalled back to Dax.

Comment: Actually Jadzia specifically recalls Curzon's memories from when he was bonded to Odo at the end of the episode.  She remarks on how she had no idea until then how wonderful it was to Odo to change shapes and just freely ooze about.  Of course, that was a particularly exceptional case. And doesn't address the OP's desire for memories recalled *before* the bond.